# solving a trigonometric equation Cos(x+30°)=cos(x+60°)

Tags: trigonometry

$cos(x+30°)=cos(x+60°)$

In the start i used the addition formula and i get : $√3/2cosx-1/2sinx-1/2sinx+√3/2cosx=0$ 
and at the end i get like 
$cos(x+30°)=0$ 
but i don't know is it right.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What does imply $cos(a)=cos(b)$ ?

Comment: Even if this is not what to do, your expansion is wrong. You should have arrived to $\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) (\sin (x)+\cos (x))=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Notice that (and we can see it on the unit trigonometric circle)

$$\cos a=\cos b\iff a=b+2k\pi\quad\text{or}\quad a=-b+2k\pi,\quad k\in\Bbb Z$$
can you take it from here?